# exc_bad_access accessing a static member in category

Tags: ios, multithreading, nsdate, nscalendar, objective-c-category

I had using this [NSDate Extension](https://github.com/erica/NSDate-Extensions) for a time but now it just start crashing while calling [NSDate currentCalendar] the `dateAtStartOfDay` method from multimple threads and some tiem i receive a crash with **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** and a memory address.

The issue is that when i'm accesing that `static NSCalendar *sharedCalendar` from multiple threads at the same time i get that error.

Shared access:

```
+ (NSCalendar *) currentCalendar
{
    static NSCalendar *sharedCalendar = nil;
    if (!sharedCalendar)
        sharedCalendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
    return sharedCalendar;
}
```

How I can fix this ?

here is the error:

[image]
and when printing the objects:(sometimes the [NSDate currentCalendar] return the address)

[image]

Comment: `NSCalendar` isn't thread safe. You are going to have to add code to ensure there is no concurrent access to the shared calendar.

Comment: @rmaddy this is why the method store the calendar into a static variable, please see the updated question.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that you are calling methods on this shared static `NSCalendar` instance concurrently on multiple threads. `NSCalendar` doesn't support that.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? Was it actually a threading problem?

Comment: @Gazzini i just post an answer , that solution is what helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the solution that is applied right now is:

```
+ (NSCalendar *)currentCalendar
{
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedCalendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
    });

    return sharedCalendar;
}
```

i just wrap the initialisation of the `sharedCalendar` in a `dispatch_once`. Almost half year no issue.